# How to gernerate Recurly API key implementing with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recurly

How to generate Recurly API key, implementing through ruby?
I want to use recurly api for billing functionality.
And please suggest me something because i am new to Recurly

When I am creating an account, it gives me *Access denied* :

```
account = Recurly::Account.create( 
                      :account_code => '1', 
                      :email => 'verena@example.com', 
                      :first_name => 'Verena', 
                      :last_name => 'Example' )
```

Comment: When i am creating account,

account = Recurly::Account.create(
  :account_code => '1',
  :email        => 'verena@example.com',
  :first_name   => 'Verena',
  :last_name    => 'Example'
)

It gives me Access denied.

Answer (score 1):

There's [an open source client](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-ruby) available for recurly.

Check [the Recurly documentation for Ruby](https://docs.recurly.com/client-libraries/ruby), it explains how to setup your application for using this client.

There's also a ruby on rails sample app, using this ruby recurly client [here](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-ruby-demo)

You can generate an initializer file with the following command :

```
rails g recurly:config
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.recurly.com/api/basics/authentication

If I understand your situation correctly, you just need to generate it on the [page](https://app.recurly.com/go/developer/api_access)